# How to Concatenate Any Number of Arrays and Returns a Copy of the Array As Many Numbers Specified

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to set up a function that takes an array (as the first parameter) and a number (as the second), that which returns a copy of the array as many numbers as specified in the second parameter (i.e. if the array is [1,2,3] in the first argument and the number 4 is the second argument, the function should return [1,2,3,1,2,3, 1,2,3 1,2,3]. Thanks in advance for the guidance.

I have been stuck on this problem for quite some time and I've tried to concatenate the arrays to one another but it doesn't work. When I run my code I see that the arrays are returning the numbers specified on the second argument, but it's not merging them. How would I go about doing that?

```
function expand(array, number){
    let arr = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < number; i++){
      console.log(arr.concat(array));

    }

    return arr;
}






expand([1,2,3], 5)

// })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign back the new array returned by [Array.concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) to the `arr` variable:

```js
function expand(array, number)
{
    let arr = [];

    for (i = 0; i < number; i++)
    {
        arr = arr.concat(array);
    }
    
    return arr;
}

console.log(expand([1,2,3], 5));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Or, you can go with a recursive approach too:

```js
function expand(array, number, res=[])
{
    return !number ? res : expand(array, number - 1, res.concat(array));
}

console.log(expand([1,2,3], 5));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Or if your array consist only of numbers, maybe you can use [Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) in conjuntion with the string utility [String.repeat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat):

```js
function expand(array, number)
{
    return Array.from(array.join("").repeat(number), Number);
}

console.log(expand([1,2,3], 5));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Comment: Thank you.for the help. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I like this for succinctness - just `push()` while counting down in a while loop. Unlike `concat`, `push()` manipulate the array in place rather than retuning the new array:

```js
function expand(array, number, res = []){
  while(number-->0) res.push(...array)
  return res
}

console.log(expand([1,2,3], 3))
```

If you're game for the new [`flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) you can also use this one-liner:

```js
const expand = (array, number) => Array(number).fill(array).flat()

console.log(expand([1, 2, 3], 3))
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try using [`Array.prototype.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) as well.

```
var arr1 = [1,2,3];
var n=4;

var arr2 = expandArray(arr1,4);
console.log(arr2);

function expandArray(arr1,n) {
  var arr3 = [];

  for (var i = 0; i<n;i++) {
    arr3.push(...arr1);

  }
  return arr3;

}
```